# what @property setup exactly? and "getter=" do?

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter, getter

1.
Please confirm if I understand this correctly.

I have a line of code below,

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Month *august;`
and it will setup below.

1 setter
`-(void)setAugust:(Month *)august`

1 getter
`-(Month *)august`

and 1 ivar `_august`

and when I implement my own setter, I have to
`_august = august` (inside of setter to assign the ivar with proper value)

2.
Another question, 
some example shows:
when I implement setter , they use 
`_ivar = ivar;`
and others use
`@synthesize _ivar = ivar;`.

I believe @synthesize was used to create setter and getter but it's abbreviated as of iOS 6, right?
I am confused of using the statement while implementing setter.

3.
`@property (nonatomic, getter=isPlan) BOOL plan;`

What does "getter=" exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are correct (after the 2 typos I corrected - if they weren't typos make sure you understand the difference).
2. `@synthesize` used to be required but isn't any more. This is a feature of Xcode (the compiler really), not any version of iOS.
3. It generates the `getter` method with a different signature:

Normal:

```
- (BOOL)plan;
```

Specified:

```
- (BOOL)isPlan;
```